# How to initialize System.getProperty(path) to get the path of local system while running mockito test case

Tags: junit, mockito

It is related to mockito Test Case.
While running my test case, I need to initialize a string which contains a local system path to read the property file, but every time I get `null`.

I am using `System.getProperty(constant);` to retreive place of property file path, but it returns `null`.

Comment: please provide some code to show us what you have tried so far

Comment: It is like below code    MyMockitoTestClass{}

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperty(constant);
```

The line failes due to that the property is not set.

How do you run the test cases? Eclipse, maven or something else?

Comment: i am running test case through eclipse

Comment: These properties are often set from outside call(java -Dkey= value javaclass. If you have set the property(System.setProperty("key","value");, first then will it return something.

Comment: thank you very much sir. It worked i initialize System.setProperty(key, value) inside my test class.